# Calculating number of times each IAT was called from PE

Tags: python-3.x, dllimport, portable-executable, malware-detection

I am trying to calculate the number of times each IAT-import address table was called by a PE. It is like this:

```
counter=0

for entry in file.DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT:

    print (entry.dll)

    for imp in entry.imports:

        print ('\t', hex(imp.address), imp.name)

        counter=counter+1  

    print(entry.dll,":",counter)
```

The output is somewhat like this:

b'KERNEL32.dll'

```
 0x180006000 b'GetProcAddress'

 0x180006008 b'LoadLibraryA'

 0x180006010 b'IsProcessorFeaturePresent'

 0x180006018 b'GetStartupInfoW'

 0x180006020 b'SetUnhandledExceptionFilter'

 0x180006028 b'UnhandledExceptionFilter'

 0x180006030 b'IsDebuggerPresent'

 0x180006038 b'RtlVirtualUnwind'

 0x180006040 b'RtlLookupFunctionEntry'

 0x180006048 b'RtlCaptureContext'

 0x180006050 b'InitializeSListHead'

 0x180006058 b'DisableThreadLibraryCalls'

 0x180006060 b'GetSystemTimeAsFileTime'

 0x180006068 b'GetCurrentThreadId'

 0x180006070 b'GetCurrentProcessId'

 0x180006078 b'QueryPerformanceCounter'

 0x180006080 b'GetModuleHandleW'
```

b'KERNEL32.dll' : 17

b'MSVCP140.dll'

```
 0x180006090 b'?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPEBD@Z'

 0x180006098 b'?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPEBD@Z'

 0x1800060a0 b'?_Xbad_alloc@std@@YAXXZ'
```

b'MSVCP140.dll' : 20

b'VCRUNTIME140.dll'

```
 0x1800060b0 b'_purecall'

 0x1800060b8 b'__std_terminate'

 0x1800060c0 b'memmove'

 0x1800060c8 b'_CxxThrowException'

 0x1800060d0 b'__std_type_info_destroy_list'

 0x1800060d8 b'__RTDynamicCast'

 0x1800060e0 b'memcpy'

 0x1800060e8 b'__C_specific_handler'

 0x1800060f0 b'__std_exception_copy'

 0x1800060f8 b'__std_exception_destroy'

 0x180006100 b'__CxxFrameHandler3'

 0x180006108 b'memset'
```

b'VCRUNTIME140.dll' : 32

But it should count each entry individually. For example, MSVCP140.dll should be counted as '3' and not '20'. Any help would be gladly appreciated.

Comment: Just move the `counter` variable below `for entry ...`. As a side note, it will only count the number of imports from a particular DLL, not the number of times the imports are called from a PE (as your title seems to imply).

Comment: Yes, I did that. Thank you for your help.